# How to attach an element on the dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a guitar addict and I try to make a UI for guitar tablature.

In my js code, you can see

> var notes = ['s6f1', 's5f5', 's4f7', 's3f6', 's2f5', 's1f3', 's6f8',
>   's5f1', 's4f6', 's3f1', 's2f3', 's1f3', 's6f9', 's5f17', 's4f19'];

's6f1' means string 6 & fret 1 and I want to show it on tablature. The way I show this is to put a "1" on string 6. Please the picture below. In my code, I basically traverse the notes array and attach each note on tablature .  I define each 6 six lines as a group.  After a group is filled with 4 notes, a new group is shown.  Since In my real application, I do not know how many notes that notes array has(In this examples, I just simplify there are 15 notes), I have to dynamically create each group and assign each line a unique id.  My question is that I do not know how to attach the number on the string. For instance, after dynamically create a "six-line", how do I **attach** the number on the correct line. I think the challenge in my question is that I cannot predefine the location of six-liner in html.  The code below is the html, css, js code that I wrote.  Hope someone could help me out.  Thank you in advance.

[image]

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="code.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code_js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    </div>

        <div id = "output">

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.deco {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 120px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}


#output {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    background-color: yellow;
}


.six_line {
    width: 125px;
    height: 80px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

js:

```
"use strict"
var count = 0;
var group = -1;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var notes = ['s6f1', 's5f5', 's4f7', 's3f6', 's2f5', 's1f3', 's6f8', 's5f1', 's4f6', 's3f1', 's2f3', 's1f3', 's6f9', 's5f17', 's4f19'];
    hideNote(notes, 0);
});

function hideNote(notes, i) {
    var x = -2;
    if(count == 4) {count = 0;}
    if(count++ == 0) {
        group++;
        makeItHappen();
    } 
    var ns4 = notes[i];
    // retrive the info of string
    var ns2 = ns4.substring(0,2);
    x = parseInt(ns4.substring(1,2)) + (group*6);
   **/*How to attach fret(#) on the string*
       // finds the line with corresponding id
       $('#hr' + x).attr('class', '?');
   */**
    hide(function(){
        if(++i < notes.length) {
            hideNote(notes, i);
        }
    },notes[i]);
}

function hide(callback, note) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback();
    }, 1000); 
}

function makeItHappen() {
    var six = document.createElement('div');
    six.className = "six_line";
    for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        var hr = document.createElement('hr');
        hr.className = "deco";
        hr.id = "hr" + (group * 6 + i);
        six.append(hr);
    }
    $('#output').append(six);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest some modifications in your code.
Starting with the function that creates your strings:

```
function makeItHappen(nbGroup) {  
    for(var g = 1; g <= nbGroup; g++){
        var six = document.createElement('div');
        six.className = "six_line";
        for (var i = 6; i >= 1; i--) {
            var string = document.createElement('div');
            string.className = "deco";
            string.id = "string" + ('G' + g + 'S' + i);
            six.append(string);
        } 
        $('#output').append(six);
    }
}
```

That will create all your groups of strings at the same time. It becomes easily to attribute an explicit ID for each of them : `strGiSj` where `i` is the group and `j` the string in the group.

Next, how about the `hideNode` function:

```
function hideNote(notes) {
    makeItHappen(Math.ceil(notes.length / 4));

    notes.forEach(function(n, i){
        var values = n.match(/s(\d)f(\d)/); // values[1] = string, values[2] = fret
        var parentEl = $("#stringG" + (Math.ceil((i + 0.5) / 4)) + "S" + values[1]);
        var child = $("<div></div>")
            .addClass("fret")
            .css("left", (10+ (i%4) * 25) + "px")
            .text(values[2]);

        parentEl.append(child)
    });
}
```

We create the amount of groups needed (amount of notes / 4 rounded to next int). For each note in your array, we retrieve the string and the fret with a regular expression `/s(\d)f(\d+)/`:

- `\d` matches a digit
- `\d+` matches one or more digits
- Parenthesis allow to retrieve values easily

Next, we just have to retrieve the appropriate group, and retrieve the associated `div` with good `id`, then create the fret element and place it.

The full code looks like this:

```
"use strict"

$(document).ready(function() {
    var notes = ['s6f1', 's5f5', 's4f7', 's3f6', 's2f5', 's1f3', 's6f8', 's5f1', 's4f6', 's3f1', 's2f3', 's1f3', 's6f9', 's5f17', 's4f19'];
    hideNote(notes);
});

function hideNote(notes) {

    makeItHappen(Math.ceil(notes.length / 4))

    notes.forEach(function(n, i){
      var values = n.match(/s(\d)f(\d+)/);
      var parentEl = $("#stringG" + (Math.ceil((i + 0.5) / 4)) + "S" + values[1]);
      var child = $("<div></div>")
        .addClass("fret")
        .css("left", (10+ (i%4) * 25) + "px")
        .text(values[2]);

      parentEl.append(child)
    })
}

function makeItHappen(nbGroup) {  
  for(var g = 1; g <= nbGroup; g++){
    var six = document.createElement('div');
    six.className = "six_line";
    for (var i = 6; i >= 1; i--) {
        var string = document.createElement('div');
        string.className = "deco";
        string.id = "string" + ('G' + g + 'S' + i);
        six.append(string);
    }
    $('#output').append(six);
  }
}
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNabxm) with a working sample.

Comment: You have no idea how helpful it is.  Thank you so much.